# Function is unable to transform a list element if wrapped in a for function

Tags: python, list, function, random

Can someone explain the behavior of the following code?

```
import random


abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
xyz = ['x', 'y', 'z']


def randomize(x):
    random.shuffle(x)
    x = x[0]
    print('expected: ' + str(x))
    return x


random_list = [abc, xyz]

for r in random_list:
    r = randomize(x=r)


print('-----\n')

print('actual: ' + str(abc))
print('actual: ' + str(xyz))
```

If I run the code outside the for loop, it will behave as expected:

```
abc = randomize(abc)
print('actual: ' + str(abc))
```

I would expect the return to match what is being printed in the function, however, that is not the case.

Comment: What are you expecting? Can you please include that in question. Thanks

Comment: I edited the code so that it is more clear. Hope it helps. Thank you.

Comment: You want only `print('expected: ' + str(x)) ` when you print after `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, check the edit again, if the function is applied on abc outside of the for loop, it will shuffle and modify abc. If it is run within the for loop, it only shuffles abc and does not return the 0th, list element, thus not really modifying it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get (for example) expected: b, expected: y and actual ['b', 'c', 'a'] actual: ['y', 'x', 'z'] which is correct since `b` is the first element of the first actual and same for y for the second one.

Comment: You did reproduce it though, check what the function is doing  - x = x[0], it should output the 0th list element, however your actual contains the entire list, just shuffled.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.** See: How to create a [example]. You never stated what's wrong with your code. You should provide the result you expect and what you get instead. The code does exactly what it has been written to do, if you wrote the code incorrectly we cannot tell what you wanted to do instead.

Comment: @michael0196 Why? You never assign `abc` and `xyz` again. Maybe you simply have no clue how bindings work in Python?

Comment: This looks like an issue of variables and scope. If you put `print(r)` inside your `for r in ...` loop, you'll see the value you expect. However, because of scoping, you're not changing the actual list.

Comment: @Bakariu If you read carefully, I never said anything is wrong with the code. I asked someone to explain the behavior, so maybe I had no clue how bindings worked in Python which is exactly what my question implies. Maybe try and read first before being condescending. Nonetheless, the code reproduces and explains the issue if you run it so I really don't get what your issue is. How is expected and actual not clear enough for you?

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you. That clearly explains the behavior in question.

Answer (score 1):

So we start with `random_list = [abc, xyz]`

```
for r in random_list:
```

At this point, `r` refers to the list `abc`.

```
    r = randomize(x=r)
```

`r` now points to a new object, returned from `randomize`, a different thing that what `abc` is pointing to.

One workaround is

```
for i in len(random_list):
    random_list[i] = randomize(random_list[i])
```

or

```
random_list = [randomize(r) for element in random_list]
```